# Why GraphQl force you to match the variables requirements on the queries?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

Let's say my GraphQl server have a query defined like this

```
query getUser(name: String!)
```

then I make a query like this

```
query getUser(name: String) {
  getUser(name: $name)
...
```

I get an error like this

> Variable type 'String' doesn't match expected type 'String!

Why he is trying to match that instead of check if the value was already passed? The way I see it this is unnecessary and forces the client app to change for stupid reasons. Maybe I am missing something here.

Answer (score 4):

The `!` indicates a type as non-nullable. A non-nullable argument cannot be omitted or be passed a value of null. If the argument is passed a variable, the type of that variable must also be non-nullable. If the variable type was nullable, it would mean `null` would be a valid value for the variable, but `null` is **not** a valid value for the argument.

On the other hand, an argument whose type is *nullable* may accept variables that are either nullable or non-nullable because there is no incompatibility in the ranges of possible values.

This is all outlines in the Validation section of the [spec](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Validation.Variables).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `String` with `ID!` worked for me

```
query getUser(name: ID!) {
  getUser(name: $name)
```